# Azure SQL database availability after creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to configure an Azure pipeline where I create a copy of a production database to create a "pre-prod" environment.

After create that database I need to run some queries in the freshly created database. The problem is database is not available right away. As the process is automatic I need to know for how long I need to wait.

I put a wait step for 5 minutes but sometimes is not enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a simple check of DB availability, through Az module, or CLI?

```
do {
  sleep 120
  $status = "Offline"
  try{
    $status = (Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup01" -ServerName "server01"-DatabaseName "MyDataBase").Status
  }
  catch
  {
    "Database not available yet"
  }
} while ($status -ne "Online")
```

Comment: I use your base idea to solve my problem (I already request some changes in your answer to match what I do). I use Azure PowerShell.

Comment: @Gelásio Can you share your changes here? I will help you update these changes into Oleh Tarasenko's answer.

Comment: I don't see any request for edit, @Gelásio can you please write what is need to be changed. Thank you!

Comment: I already try another time. I don't know why my first request for edit simply disappear. Here it is my second try: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27175641

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Azure portal's [query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-portal) to query an Azure SQL Database to check DB availability.

The query editor is a tool in the Azure portal for running SQL queries against your database in Azure SQL Database or data warehouse in Azure Synapse Analytics.

**Note**: The query editor uses ports 443 and 1443 to communicate. Ensure you have enabled outbound HTTPS traffic on these ports. You also need to [add your outbound IP address to the server's allowed firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart) to access your databases and data warehouses.

For more query editor considerations, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-portal#query-editor-considerations).